# How does Azure CosmosDB manage new Regions?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, region

I added a new region to cosmosdb and now when launching heavy operations using stored procedures the first one is maxed out / rate limited but the new one is totally idle according to the metrics screen

Is the dispatch of operations between regions when the stored procedure runs silent or is all my data in one region while the new one remained empty/unused ?

If so, how could I reshuffle the partitions among the regions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosmos DB does replicate all data into all your regions, not just single partitions etc. So any request will end up in one region only and will only be served from one region. Which region you hit with a request can either be configured in the request or is otherwise just determined by proximity to the nearest region.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/global-dist-under-the-hood

Comment: Do you know which param is to be passed with the query to set the region ? (either http REST or with the python package)

Comment: So far I've only used that with the C# SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.connectionpolicy.preferredlocations?view=azure-dotnet But I'd assume something similar exists for python sdk as well

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cosmos/azure.cosmos.documents.connectionpolicy?view=azure-python